# Opening a file inside the terminal

Tags: macos, bash

I want to open files inside the terminal, like with vim or whatever, but I have no idea how. For example, instead of opening a .js file with atom, now I open it inside the terminal with vim. Any ideas?

I think you could use the Appify script, but I don't know how to make it work with opening files. This would mean that you open the file by double clicking on it in finder, and opening it into terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Just type `vim file.js` into the terminal, where `file.js` is the file you want to open.

Comment: ah...  I forgot to mention... I wanted to open it application-style, like by double-clicking on the file in finder.

Comment: @RishiKothari How do you want it to display? I guess you could do `atom file.js` if you want to open the file with Atom from the terminal.

Comment: Yeah.. you know how you open a file with an app by double-clicking it? I was wondering if you could do that but instead of opening it with an app, you did it with the terminal.

Comment: @RishiKothari Try doing `open file.js`?

Comment: Oof.. I'm not explaining this too well, am I? I don't want to open the file through the terminal, but rather by double clicking on the file to open the terminal with the file open.

Comment: Oh now I get it. [This might help?](https://superuser.com/a/139949/568230)

Comment: Aaaaah... thank you so, so, so much! That works!